# Elastic Search is running fine and it is active but i am getting error in the logs. Also getting error in my filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

I have two external `servers/VMs named sangh2 and sangh1`. On sangh2, I have successfully installed `Elasticsearch (ES) and Kibana`, and I am able to access Kibana via a browser. However, when I check the logs of Elasticsearch, I am encountering the following error:

```
 [priyaansh-stat-test-vm\] publish_address {'sangh2 ip':9300}, bound_addresses 
 {sangh2:9300}
 [priyaansh-stat-test-vm\] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, 
 enforcing bootstrap checks
 [priyaansh-stat-test-vm\] node validation exception
 [1\] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the 
 following \[1\] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
 bootstrap check failure \[1\] of \[1\]: the default discovery settings are 
 unsuitable for production use; at least one of \[discovery.seed_hosts, 
 discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes\] must be configured
```

My configuration setting are as following:

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: \["IP of sangh2"\]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: \["myHostname"\]
```

My objective is to push log data from my 'sangh1' VM into the Elasticsearch VM 'sangh2', but I am unable to resolve this error despite trying various configuration settings.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions you can provide to help me resolve this issue. Thank you in advance for your assistance.